# Less Than 1 Frame Switching Between Multiple Cameras in Python OpenCV2

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, video-processing

Does anyone have better idea on how to quickly switch between an array of web cameras controlled by a python open CV2 program. I would like it to have no noticeable pause between switching cameras. I am willing to go to other languages, maybe C++?

What I have so far:

```
#%% import the opencv library
import cv2
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process, Manager
import time
import keyboard
import glob
import threading
import signal
import sys

#%%

baseVidList = glob.glob("/dev/video*")
baseVidList = baseVidList[:-2]

#%%
manager = Manager()
selectedCam = manager.Value('i', 0)
endSignal = manager.Value('i', 0)
qqq = Queue()
vidDict = {}
  
# define a video capture object
for device in baseVidList:
    vidDict[device] = lambda: cv2.VideoCapture(f"{device}")

#%%
ejections = []
for device, capDevice in vidDict.items():
    vidDict[device] = capDevice()
    if vidDict[device].isOpened():
        print(f"{device} Sucess")
        vidDict[device].set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'))
    else:
        print(f"{device} Failed, Ejecting")
        vidDict[device].release()
        ejections.append(device)

for eject in ejections:
    vidDict.pop(eject)

#%%
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

#### Functions ####

# Thread class
class VideoCaptureThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, device, camID, endSignal):
        super().__init__()
        self.camID = camID
        self.device = device
        self.stopped = False
        self.fps = 10
        self.endSignal = endSignal

    def run(self):
        print("RUNNNN", self.endSignal != 1)
        while self.endSignal != 1:
            start_time = time.time()
            print("S cam is:", selectedCam.value)
            ret, frame = self.device.read()

            if ret and selectedCam.value == self.camID:
                # print(self.camID, xW, yH)
                cv2.putText(frame,f"{self.camID}",(100,100),font,1,(255,0,0),1)
                qqq.put(frame)

            # Control the frame rate
            sleep_time = 1/self.fps - (time.time() - start_time)
            if sleep_time > 0:
                time.sleep(sleep_time)

    def stop(self):
        self.stopped = True
        self.device.release()

# Multiprocessing thread launch
def runCamera(device, camID):
    # assert cap.isOpened()

    # Usage
    capture_thread = VideoCaptureThread(device, camID, endSignal) # src can be a filepath or a device index
    capture_thread.start()

    # # To stop the thread
    # capture_thread.stop()

# Display Process
def runViewer():
    while endSignal != 1:
        # print("Qlen: ", qqq.qsize())
        if qqq.empty() != True:
            frame = qqq.get()
            fy, fx, _  = frame.shape 
            frame = cv2.resize(frame,(int(2*fx),int(2*fy)))
            cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

            while qqq.qsize() > 0: # Empty the Q
                qqq.get()

# Signal Handler
def signal_handler(sig, arg2):
    print("Exiting...")
    endSignal.value = 1
    sys.exit(0)


#### MAIN ####
if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    processes = []
    idx = 0

    # Setup the cameras
    for device, capDevice in vidDict.items():
        if capDevice.isOpened():
            processes.append(Process(target=runCamera, args=(capDevice,idx)))
            idx = idx + 1
        else:
            print(f"Ejecting: {device}")

    numProcesses = len(processes)
    print(f"Processes: {numProcesses}")
    processes.append(Process(target=runViewer))

    # Launch the processes
    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    # Keyboard control
    while endSignal != 1:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('d'):  # if key 'q' is pressed 
            print('You Pressed d Key!')
            selectedCam.value = (selectedCam.value + 1) % numProcesses
            time.sleep(250/1000)

        if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):  # if key 'q' is pressed 
            print('You Pressed a Key!')
            selectedCam.value = (selectedCam.value - 1) % numProcesses
            time.sleep(250/1000)

    # Graceful shutdown?
    print("START END")
    
    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    for device, capDevice in vidDict.items():
        capDevice.release()

    # Destroy all the windows
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code seems to support up to 5 cameras without issue. Extending to 10 sort of works but some of the cameras seem not to send data. The combination of threading and multiprocessing is an attempt to have the next frame ready for immediate addition to the queue and thereby there is no pause in switching cameras as would happen if we had to go through the whole cap setup and read process.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Run each camera capture in a separate thread by using multi-threading. In this method, while the other threads are capturing the following frame, the main thread can continue to process the currently shown frame.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Good instincts. That is what I tried above. First it uses multiprocessing to allow each core to employ multi threading. Then each process uses multi threading to prevent IO blocking. In theory this should work. However it does not seem to scale past ~5-7 cameras before cameras stop adding to the Queue.

Comment: You have a good approach in the code but you can further optimize it with circular buffer to pre-fetch the frames.

Comment: Not sure what effect that would have on the latency of this? At least 1 frame delay in the buffer?